# I get error "The named parameter 'body' isn't defined." after I try to use to pdf function to print a table in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

So I get error "The named parameter 'body' isn't defined." after I try to use to pdf function to print a table, the main package used here is package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw. I created a timetable and I want to display it when I click my pdf button but when I write the code for the table inside my doc.addpage I get the error body is not defined.

> My code is as follows:
>
> Imported packages...

```
class TableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TableWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TableState createState() => _TableState();

}

class _TableState extends State<TableWidget> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            title: const Text('Timetable Generated'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Table(
                defaultColumnWidth: const FlexColumnWidth(1.0),
                border: TableBorder.all(
                    color: Colors.black, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                children: [
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 1 \n 08:05 - 08:45',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 2 \n 09:00 - 09:40',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 3 \n 09:50 - 10:30',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 4 \n 10:40 - 11:20',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 5 \n 11:30 - 12:10',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 6 \n 12:20 - 13:00',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 7 \n 14:00 - 14:40',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Mo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Turkish', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Geography', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Business', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Business', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Tu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('PE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('PE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('We', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Computer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('CVC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Thu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Computer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('History', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Fri', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Accounting', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Accounting', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    fixedSize: const Size.square(40),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                onPressed: _createExcel,
                child: const Text('To Excel')),

            TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: const Size.square(30),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: _createPdf,
                child: const Text('To PDF')),
          ]))),
    );
  }
//Buttons

//Create PDF and display text
  void _createPdf() async {
    final doc = pw.Document();
    
    /// for using an image from assets
    // final image = await imageFromAssetBundle('assets/image.png');

    doc.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Table(
                defaultColumnWidth: const FlexColumnWidth(1.0),
                border: TableBorder.all(
                    color: Colors.black, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                children: [
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 1 \n 08:05 - 08:45',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 2 \n 09:00 - 09:40',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 3 \n 09:50 - 10:30',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 4 \n 10:40 - 11:20',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 5 \n 11:30 - 12:10',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 6 \n 12:20 - 13:00',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Lesson 7 \n 14:00 - 14:40',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Mo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Turkish', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Geography', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Business', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Business', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Tu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('PE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('PE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('We', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Computer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Portuguese', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Chemistry', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('CVC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Thu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Biology', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Computer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('English', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('History', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Fri', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Maths', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Accounting', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Accounting', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('Physics', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                    Column(children: const [
                      Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0))
                    ]),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ),]))); // Center
        },
      ),
    );
    await Printing.layoutPdf(
        onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => doc.save());
    //To share to other apps
    await Printing.sharePdf(
        bytes: await doc.save(), filename: 'my-document.pdf');

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you eed to change `body` with `child` here:

instead of this:

```
  return pw.Center(
        body: Center(
  // ...
```

replace it with this:

```
  return pw.Center(
        child: Center(
  // ...
```

only the `Scaffold` widget accepts a `body` property to set screen widgets, but other Flutter widgets and `pw.Center` accepts `child` property.

Comment: When I do that I get this error The argument type 'Center' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.

Comment: sorry, I searched for the error directly, I didn't notice it's wrapped with the  `doc.addPage`

Comment: are you sure you can set widgets inside that function as I see from the package's page, they allow nested `pw` widget types like pw.Center and pw.Text..

Comment: No, actually I'm not sure